# How to modify the descriptor using decorators in typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator

So I have this method that I want to turn into a decorator:

```
function MethodRead< Data, Output extends Mongo.Cursor<Data> >( 
    method: (...args: any[]) => Output, 
    opt: IOptions = {} 
) {
    return (...args: any[]) => {
        const sub = doSomeProcessing(method(...args), opt);
        return {
            ready: () => sub.ready(),
            fetch: () => sub.fetch(),
        };
    };
}
```

The typing on this method (with the exception of the arguments) all matches and works well.

However, when I try to turn it into a decorator, it seems that typescript just has no clean way of dealing with this logic...

```
function DecoratorRead<Data>(opt: IOptions) {
    return <C, K extends keyof C> ( 
        target: C, 
        propName: K, 
        descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<C[K]> 
    ): TypedPropertyDescriptor<Reader<Data>> => {
        descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => {
            const sub = doSomeProcessing(method(...args), opt);
            return {
                ready: () => sub.ready(),
                fetch: () => sub.fetch(),
            };
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

so, the errors I get with typescript are as such:

```
Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<C[K]>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<Reader<Data>>'.
  Type 'C[K]' is not assignable to type 'Reader<Data>'.

Type '(...args: any[]) => { ready: () => boolean; fetch: () => Data; }' is not assignable to type 'Method<Data>'.
  Type '{ ready: () => boolean; fetch: () => Data; }' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
```

Here are some additional types for you to help with:

```
interface IOptions {
     auth: boolean;
}
type Method<Data> = (...args: any[]) => Data;
type Reader<Data> = (...args: any[]) => {
    ready: () => boolean;
    fetch: () => Data;
}

function doSomeProcessing<Data>( data: Data , opt: IOptions ) : {
    ready: () => boolean;
    fetch: () => Data;
};
```